# Wrapping lines in a paragraph with header and footer lines

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Say I have a paragraph like this

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I want to select all and then transform like this

```
:start
line1
:end

:start
line2
:end

:start
line3
:end
```

Don't ask me why, we have some strange text transformation requirements. I could do it with Python but how can I do this in Vim.

I know I would start by selecting the block via `V`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic `:s` command can do stuff like this easily. e.g. type

```
:s/.*/:start\r&\r:end\r/
```

It looks like

```
:'<,'>s/.*/:start\r&\r:end\r/
```

on the command line if you select the area first, because `'<` and `'>` denote the visually selected range.

`.*` matches the entire line, `\r` is inserting newline, the `&` in the pattern represents the matched text (`:h s/\r`, `:h s/\&`)